# Unicode characters got garbled when viewing it in jsp page and data is read from cassandra

Tags: java, jsp, unicode, cassandra

Below is the problem description.

1. I have a rest API by which I am saving some data in Cassandra.

Data sent in post body:

```
\u001b test description \u001b
```

Data stored in cassandra:

```
\x1b test description \x1b
```

I am using `Cassandra 3.11.4` for saving it was saved diff characters other than Unicode.

While retrieving and showing in UI(for which encode-type set to utf-8), Unicode characters got garbled and they are not displayed in UI.

Please help me with the solution to display Unicode characters in UI.

Comment: The data that is shown for Cassandra is correct representation of UTF-8 characters... What is the problem? What driver are you using for accessing Cassandra? What data type is used for a column - `text` or `ascii` ?

Comment: Data type used on cassandra side is text. The driver used is cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0 jar. How can I read unicode characters through java code as in my case they are getting garbled

Comment: Cassandra driver performs all conversions automatically - internally Cassandra uses UTF-8 for `text` columns. I would suggest to check your servlet/etc.